# My React Simple counter doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I starting to learn React and I was wondering why my Counter it's not working :(
My objective is: When you press the button, Counter function start to "count" and render "count" state in the td.  I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";


function Clock() {
  const customStyle = {
    fontSize: "100px"
  };
  const tdStyle = "px-3 border border-dark border-3 rounded bg-secondary";
  //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// THIS FUNCTION 
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  function Counter(){
    setCount(count + 1)
    setInterval(Counter, 1000)
  }  
 

  return (
    <div className="rounded border border-dark border-3">
      <table>
        <tr style={customStyle}>
          <td className={tdStyle}>
            <i className="fa-solid fa-clock"></i>
          </td>
          <td className={tdStyle}>0</td>
          <td className={tdStyle}>0</td>
          <td className={tdStyle}>0</td>
          <td className={tdStyle}>0</td>
          <td className={tdStyle}>0</td>
          <td className={tdStyle}>{count}</td>    //here is showed
        </tr>
      </table>
      <button onClick={Counter}>Pulsar</button>    //button
    </div>
  );
}

export default Clock;
```

This works with real seconds

```
function Counter(){
    setCount(new Date().getSeconds())
    setInterval(Counter, 1000)
  }
```

But it is not what I want. I want a simple counter.

In addition, How could I use "onLoad" event in this code? for when page is loaded It start counting and rendering it in the page?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to put your setInterval in a useEffect hook because you are currently creating a new interval every time your state updates (i.e every second), which will drastically slow down your app. Secondly, you should use the useEffect cleanup function to remove the interval each time your component re-renders to prevent duplicate interval creation. Finally, given your state depends on a previous state snapshot (i.e the previous count value), you should update your state using a callback (to ensure you access the most recent state snapshot)

```
useEffect(() => {

  function counter(){
    setCount(prevState => prevState + 1)
  }

  let countInterval = setInterval(counter, 1000)

  return () => clearInterval(countInterval)

}, [])
```

Given you are calling the useEffect every time the count updates, you could (and probably should) use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`. In that case, you wouldn't require the cleanup function.

Comment: Yeah! This works perfectly. Thank you very much, I'm going to try to understand this in a better way!

Comment: You're welcome! It's definitely worth looking at how React state updates (i.e asynchronously) and checking out the useEffect hook (it will be the solution to many of your problems as it prevents code running every time the component re-renders)

Comment: Are you sure you want `count` in the dependency list?

Comment: @BenStephens You're right; my answer originally used ```count``` within the useEffect function (thus it was required to prevent the variable being a stale closure). The above code will still work but the useEffect will run unnecessarily, so I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand how useState works correctly I believe you're running into some asynchronous issues with your count state, which would explain why your "real seconds" example works.

I would suggest moving your `setInterval()` function to a `useEffect` hook. The `useEffect` hook would also be the answer to your `onLoad` question as well.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";


function Clock() {
  const customStyle = {
    fontSize: "100px"
  };
  const tdStyle = "px-3 border border-dark border-3 rounded bg-secondary";
  //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// THIS FUNCTION 
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  setInterval(counter, 1000);
}, []);

  function Counter(){
    setCount(count + 1)
  }  
 

  return (
    <div className="rounded border border-dark border-3">
      <table>
        <tr style={customStyle}>
          <td className={tdStyle}>
            <i className="fa-solid fa-clock"></i>
          </td>
          <td className={tdStyle}>0</td>
          <td className={tdStyle}>0</td>
          <td className={tdStyle}>0</td>
          <td className={tdStyle}>0</td>
          <td className={tdStyle}>0</td>
          <td className={tdStyle}>{count}</td>    //here is showed
        </tr>
      </table>
      <button onClick={Counter}>Pulsar</button>    //button
    </div>
  );
}

export default Clock;
```

I'm not 100% positive this will work as expected as I'm unable to test it at this moment, but I believe this is what it you're looking for. Here is documentation on useEffect as well, https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: I'm afraid that this doesn't work for me :(. Nothing happens, I copy pasted your example

Comment: ```Counter``` is a closure, hence it would not be utilising an updated version of the ```count``` variable, so this answer will not work.